# I can't import the csv file into the mysql table with import wizard

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a question in connection with this problem. I try to import csv file into mysql table but I get this error message: "can't analyze file. "please try to change the encoding type. If that doesn't help, maybe the file is not: csv or the file is empty". I set the coding to utf 8 in excel when I saved the csv file but doesn't work.

Thanks your help guys :)

These are the first three rows of the csv:

[image: three row]

Comment: What ide are you using (phpmyadmin,mysqlworkbench..And please add a few rows from the csv file.

Comment: I using mysqlworkbench. This is the first three row of csv.
id Játékos neve Kor Nemzetiség Poszt Piaci érték Honnan Hova Ár Átigazolási időszak Átigazolási szezon Liga
1 Jhon Córdoba 22 Colombia CF €2.00m Granada CF 1.FSV Mainz 05 Loan fee:€600k nyár 2015/16 La liga
2 Dídac Vil? 26 Spain LB €1.00m SD Eibar AC Milan End of loan:Jun 30, 2015 nyár 2015/16 La liga
3 Carlos Bacca 28 Colombia CF €25.00m Sevilla FC AC Milan €30.00m nyár 2015/16 La liga

Comment: Shown error message is not MySQL error message. Refer to your wizard documentation for this error type troubleshooting.

Comment: *This is the first five row of csv.* Add this into the question as formatted text without any edition. Publish full importing query text. Publish full CREATE TABLE for destination table. Publish all system/session variables values relative to charset/collation. Check your file encoding (it must be UTF8 w/o BOM). *I set the coding to utf 8* In what place? There is at least 6 points where it can be done.